# Good data - debugging a graph (grf file)

Tags: gooddata, cloud-connect

I've got a graph that isn't behaving as it should in CloudConnect.

I'm running it locally, and it's completing, but not doing its work.

In an effort to figure out why this is, I've added printLog calls in many places, like the following

```
printLog(warn, 'transfrom from file ' + $in.0.fileName);
printLog(debug, 'joining etc');
```

The Phase consists of a FileList into a SimpleCopy, into a LookupJoin, a Reformat (produce SQL) and a DBInsert.

However, while I see logs for phases above, I'm not seeing anything produced in the log for any part of my phase.  All parts of the phase do report running successfully in log.  I've also done Enable Debugging on all connections in this phase.

Am I missing something to enable logging?  Is there a better way to debug processing in CloudConnect?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the problem - the FileList will succeed if the source file cannot be found, but none of the subsequent steps will then fire.  It's somewhat unintuitive, since the log files says 'succeeded'.

For debugging, after run you can access the data by right clicking on the connection, and selecting "View Data"

Sorry for the elementary question, but documentation didn't seem to cover this clearly, at least for a GoodData noob.  I'll leave it up for anyone with the same problem!